# Combination Android Nearby Connection and Video

Tags: android, android-camera, google-nearby, wifip2p, videochat

I'm a beginner and would like to start a project.

My goal is to automatically connect nearby Android phones with each other via the nearby connection api. After the connection is established the connected phones should exchange their camera view, like a video call.

Could anyone nudge me into the direction how I could start with my project?

Thank you for your thoughts, cheers!

Comment: Hi, I kind of figured out how to establish a connection but I'm puzzeld on how to transfer a video stream. Could anyone help me on how to setup the video stream? I wasn't able to use the explanation here https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/exchange-data#stream